# Correct overriding QDataStream operators and linking problems

Tags: c++, qt, overriding, qdatastream

I need override >> and << operators of QDataStream. There's my code:

```
QDataStream &operator <<(QDataStream &out, const SScenarioEntry Entry)
{
    out.writeRawData(Entry.EntryName, sizeof(Entry.EntryName));
    out << Entry.Number;
    out << Entry.Type;
    out.writeRawData(Entry.RequestString, sizeof(Entry.RequestString));
    out.writeRawData(Entry.AnswerString, sizeof(Entry.AnswerString));
    out.writeRawData(Entry.AdditionalParams, sizeof(Entry.AdditionalParams));
    out << Entry.Timeout;
    return out;
}

QDataStream &operator >>(QDataStream &in, SScenarioEntry Entry)
{
    in.readRawData(Entry.EntryName, sizeof(Entry.EntryName));
    in >> Entry.Number;
    in >> Entry.Type;
    in.readRawData(Entry.RequestString, sizeof(Entry.RequestString));
    in.readRawData(Entry.AnswerString, sizeof(Entry.AnswerString));
    in.readRawData(Entry.AdditionalParams, sizeof(Entry.AdditionalParams));
    in >> Entry.Timeout;
    return in;
}
```

After successfull compiling, I get some misunderstandable errors like this:

```
first define here
In function `Z7qt_noopv':
multiple definition of `operator>>(QDataStream&, scnent)`
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How must I define the << and >> operators for correct working;
2. If this code is correct, how to fix linking errors.

Tnx for answers.

Answer (score 1):

It's very strange, but problem was solved by dividing functions announcements and descriptions.